# Extract a specific word from string in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, pattern-matching, extract

I am using pgadmin version 1.16.1 and I need to extract the words 'login' and 'logout' from
the result column

```
url

"http:/login-v1.abcd.com/service/abc/integration" 
"http:/xxxxxxxxlogout"
"https:/login-v1.abcd.com/service"
```

Result

```
 url                                                 Action  

"http:/login-v1.abcd.com/service/abc/integration"    login 
 "http:/xxxxxxxxlogout"                              logout
"https:/login-v1.abcd.com/service"                   login
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Client and version (pgAdmin 1.16.1) are not relevant to this question. But to be safe it's always a good idea to mention them. The version of Postgres *is* relevant, but you forgot about that.

Comment: I am using postgreSQL 9.2.2

Comment: Why don't you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I tried using substring('login' from mp_logs.url) for which I did not get any result. When I used substring(mp_logs.url from 8 for 5) I got the result login, but when 'https://login..' occurs, I need to change it again to substring(mp_logs.url from 9 for 5) due to the "s" in https..So I wasn't sure how to proceed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`substring()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) with a regular expression:

```
WITH t(txt) AS (VALUES 
     ('http:/login-v1.abcd.com/service/abc/integration')
    ,('http:/xxxxxxxxlogout')
    ,('https:/login-v1.abcd.com/service')
    )
SELECT txt, substring(txt FROM '(login|logout)') AS action FROM t
```

Comment: @user2212872: Be aware that this finds the *first* match in the string. If there can be multiple matches, you would have to define what you want to do ...

Comment: All the urls in the column have only one occurrence of login/logout. So this works for now. Will change it in future if I need to. Thank you again.